# Why am I getting primary key violations when inserting these records? (EF4 Code-First)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, code-first

I have the following entity

```
public class DocumentHistory
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    public User ModifiedbyUser { get; set; }
    public string HistoryAction { get; set; }

    public virtual int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Document Document { get; set; }
}
```

In my `DbContext`, I define the keys using:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // DocumentHistory properties
        modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentHistory>()
                    .HasKey(x => new { x.DocumentId, x.DateModified });   
    }
```

In my automated integration tests, I initialize one record with

```
_doc.HistoryRecords.Add(new DocumentHistory { DateModified = DateTime.Now });
```

I then attempt to create a new record via:

```
        // Create the history record
        var history = new DocumentHistory
        {
            Name = doc.Name,
            Description = doc.Description,
            DateModified = DateTime.Now,
            HistoryAction = ScrawlConstants.HistoryActions.Update,
            ModifiedbyUser = user
        };
        doc.HistoryRecords.Add(history);
        _context.SaveChanges();
```

When `SaveChanges` occurs, the following exception occurs:

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a unique index. [ Table name = DocumentHistories,Constraint name = PK__DocumentHistories__000000000000006E ]
```

Theoretically, every record should be unique due to the difference in datetimes, but this isn't the case.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: DateTime.Now doesn't change on every read, it has an accuracy of about 15-16ms. In other words, two reads within the same 15-16ms "window" will get the same values back. Have you considered using server-generated identity keys?

Comment: I've considered it, I just thought using a DateTime would be better for querying for previous and next records, and not have to worry about the identity overflowing from too many history records

Comment: I've decided to go the route of using an identity column for the primary key, since `DateTime.Now` looks to be insufficient.  If you put that as an answer I'll mark you as the correct answer.

Comment: @Lasse: You should move your comment to answer so that @KallDrexx can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accuracy of the clock on most machines is not high enough to produce a different value every time you read it.

Instead, on a typical system the accuracy is around 10-15ms. This means that consecutive reads of the clock within the same "window" will produce the exact same value.

See the [DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) documentation for some information on this subject. Different sources of documentation gives different numbers but the relevant information is that it just isn't accurate enough. One source stipulated 1/64th of a second, which translates to 15.625ms.

You should instead switch to something that is guaranteed to be unique, such as a Guid (though you lose the ordering property of the data) or use a server-generated identity key.